# JAXB: ignore element serialization in case of special value (e.g. `null` or `Double.NaN`)

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb

I want to serialize a Java object with `JAXB`. The object has instance variables that may have special values, e.g. `null` or in another case `Double.NaN`.

How can I ignore the instance variable only, if it has this special value?

Is this possible?

---

### MWE

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyClass {

   private double value;
   private Object object;

   public void setValue(double value){this.value = value;}
   public double getValue(){return value;}

   public void setObject(Object object){this.object = object;}
   public Object getObject(){return object;}

}
```

So in case of `value` being `Double.NaN` and `object` not being `null` I'd like to get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<MyClass>
  <object>
    ...
  </object>
</MyClass>
```

and in the other case around, if `value` is not `Double.NaN` and `object` is `null` I'd like to get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<MyClass>
  <value>1.0</value>
</MyClass>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null values will by default not generate XML, so your requirement for the `object` property is already handled.

As for the special `double` value, create a dedicated method for producing the XML `value` value, and suppress the normal mapping of `value` or `getValue()` to XML.

This can be done by either annotating with [`@XmlTransient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html), or by disabling automatic property selection using [`XmlAccessType.NONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType.html#NONE), so only annotated properties are mapped to XML.

Here is example using second approach:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class MyClass {

    private double value;
    private Foo foo;

    public MyClass() {
    }
    public MyClass(double value, Foo foo) {
        this.value = value;
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void setValue(double value){this.value = value;}
    public double getValue(){return this.value;}

    public void setFoo(Foo foo){this.foo = foo;}
    @XmlElement() public Foo getFoo(){return this.foo;}

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    public Double getXmlValue() {
        if (Double.isFinite(this.value))
            return this.value;
        return null;
    }
}

public class Foo {
    @XmlElement()
    public String getBar() { return "Test"; }
}
```

*Test*

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

marshaller.marshal(new MyClass(Math.PI, null), System.out);
marshaller.marshal(new MyClass(Double.NaN, new Foo()), System.out);
```

*Output*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myClass>
    <value>3.141592653589793</value>
</myClass>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myClass>
    <foo>
        <bar>Test</bar>
    </foo>
</myClass>
```

Notice how `<foo>` is missing from the first one, because it is `null`, and `<value>` is missing from the second one, because the `NaN` value is returned as a `null` value.

Normal use of `MyClass` would still get the `NaN` value when calling `getValue()`.